# ADFS SSO fails when we Enable IE mode in MS edge

Tags: single-sign-on, microsoft-edge, adfs

Have enabled IE mode in MS edge for a website which has ADFS SSO configured and SSO fails.
Steps followed to configure IE mode in MS edge https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies
There is no SSO issues from chrome/Firefox/IE browser/MS Edge(without IE mode enabled) which rules out there is issue with ADFS configuration.

When IE mode is enabled in MS edge the SSO flow does go through configured Service Provider(SP) and Identity Provider(IDP) but when it returns it stops at https:///adfs/ls and does not move the claimsite or the website and get a generic error on the webpage

Activity ID: 668d022d-e4a7-4644-63db-0080010000c3
Error time: Thu, 22 Apr 2021 22:41:14 GMT
Cookie: enabled
User agent string: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; Zoom 3.6.0)

When we analyze ADFS Event viewer we get

Encountered error during federation passive request.
Exception details:
Microsoft.IdentityServer.RequestFailedException: MSIS7065: There are no registered protocol handlers on path /adfs/ls/ to process the incoming request.
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)*

What I have tried till now

1. Enable MS Edge in Adfs using the command ADFSProperties -WIASupportedUserAgents reference link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/configure-ad-fs-browser-wia
2. Enable IDP initiated SSO as well with command Set-AdfsProperties -EnableIdPInitiatedSignonPage $true

Comment: Installed fiddler and observed tunneling occurs when we call IE enabled website from edge to iexplore, it means all the site which is enabled IE in MS edge uses iexplore process internally and other sites that is service provider and idp still using edge

Answer (score 0):

we were able to resolve this issue after including ADFS SP and IDP in the Enterprise Mode Site List i.e. ADFS SP server should have same compact mode as website configured for IE Mode and IDP should be set as default
[my settings which worked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrL64.png)

reference url -

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-sitelist#configure-neutral-sites
- https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/discussions/ie-mode-stuck-in-authentication-loop-for-websites-using-sso/m-p/784769

Thanks